# Is there a standard definition of $\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty} a_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, definition

In my class of Time Series, the professor mentioned about the sequence of real numbers $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb Z}$ and the sum $$\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty} a_n$$

I've searched on the Internet but could not find a definition for the sum from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.
Is there a standard definition for this kind of sum?

Comment: As well as the duplicate question I've cited, see (1) [doubly infinite series in nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/doubly+infinite+series), (2) [The doubly infinite series $\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty} n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1772495) (comment by K. Reeves), (3) Steven G. Krantz, *A Guide to Complex Variables*, section 4.2.2, "Convergence of a Doubly Infinite Series".

Comment: G. J. O. Jameson, *A First Course on Complex Functions* (1970), p.91: Suppose that, for each integer $n$ (positive and negative), a complex number $a_n$ is given. If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=s_1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{-n}=s_2,$ we write  $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n=s_1+s_2.$ It is easily verified that the following statement is equivalent: given $\epsilon>0,$ there exists $N$ such that whenever $m,n>N,$ $$|(a_{-m}+\cdots+a_n)-(s_1+s_2)|\leqslant\epsilon.$$

Comment: (5) Tom M. Apostol, *Mathematical Analysis* (2nd ed. 1974), p.455 (special case, but the general implication is clear).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reference @CalumGilhooley ;)

Comment: There's more! :) (6) Lars V. Ahlfors, *Complex Analysis* (3rd ed. 1979), p.184: "$\ldots$ a $\ldots$ series of the form $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_nz^n$ $\ldots$ will be termed convergent only if the parts consisting of nonnegative powers and negative powers are separately convergent."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, for a given index set $I$, we speak of the sum of the elements $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$ and write it ass $$\sum_{i\in I} x_i.$$

However, it would be a good practice for you to show that $\sum_{i\in I} x_i$ converges in the a normed space if and only if $I$ is at most countable (i.e. finite or countable infinite).

**The definition of the sum is as follows:** Let $T$ be a countable set, then we write $$\sum_{n\in T} x_n=s$$
if for $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a finite subset $T'$ of $Τ$ such that for all finite sets $T''$ for which $T'\subset T'' \subset Τ$ we have 
$$\left|s-\sum_{n\in T''}x_n \right|< \varepsilon $$
(For definition, see e.g. Ultrametric calculus, W. H. Schikhof. CUP)

Comment: Your definition only works for absolutely convergent series. But the OP's series has an implied order of elements, in both directions. So we can make sense of a conditionally convergent series (see my answer).

Comment: @TonyK OP asks about time series.

Comment: [Time series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series) can be negative, can't they?

Comment: Well, I knew this answer and I shared it and seems that OP convinced with the answer.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb Z$ is measure space with the counting measure, and the sum
$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} a_n$$
may be defined as the integral of the function $a$ w.r.t. this measure (when it 'converges absolutely', i.e. when $a$ is integrable.)

Comment: It converges absolutely iff $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a_n^+<\infty$ **and** $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a_n^-<\infty$. I think you can also be satisfied with the weaker condition that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a_n^+<\infty$ **or** $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a_n^-<\infty$. In that case the original sum can also take values in $\{-\infty,+\infty\}$.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this is just equal to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{-n}$, as long as both series are convergent. I don't know if this is a standard definition; it just seems the obvious way to go.